# Building Arrays dynamically for inserting into SQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

I have a table with inputs in the cells. These inputs need to be inserted into SQL in a single insert. I am having trouble with just trying to build the arrays. I can push the value that is inputted into an array no problem. Its when  I push another input, the first array is overwritten. I need the array to resume or a new one to be created so  the contents of the first array are stored and the values for the second array of data are stored all in one array.

I want the user to click a save button which takes all that data and inserts it into sql. There may be only 1 array of data or 3 arrays or 10 arrays.  So I guess the question  becomes; How do I create an  array and push values inside a global array then create another array and push values in the global array without clearing the first array's values?

I haven't gotten to the AJAX request yet, just trying to build the array in preparation.

Any help is most appreciated.

HTML

```
<tr class="rows" id="row3" >
   <td class="celltimes4a"id="row3Project"></td>
   <td class="celltimes4c"id="row3Name">General</td>
   <td class="celltimes4"id="row3Sun" ><input id="num3Sun" class="alignRight"  type="text" name="hours" value="" onchange="tott(this)"></input></td>
   <td class="celltimes4"id="row3Mon" ><input id="num3Mon" class="alignRight" type="text" name="hours" value="" onchange="tott(this)"></input></td>
   <td class="celltimes4"id="row3Tue" ><input id="num3Tue" class="alignRight" type="text" name="hours" value="" onchange="tott(this)"></input></td>
   <td class="celltimes4"id="row3Wed" ><input id="num3Wed" class="alignRight" type="text" name="hours" value="" onchange="tott(this)"></input></td>
   <td class="celltimes4"id="row3Thu" ><input id="num3Thu" class="alignRight" type="text" name="hours" value="" onchange="tott(this)"></input></td>
   <td class="celltimes4"id="row3Fri" ><input id="num3Fri" class="alignRight" type="text" name="hours" value="" onchange="tott(this)"></input></td>
   <td class="celltimes4"id="row3Sat" ><input id="num3Sat" class="alignRight" type="text" name="hours" value="" onchange="tott(this)"></input></td>
   <td class="celltimes4b"id="total3"></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript

```
  var temp = {};
  var SqlArr = [];
      function tott(element) {


     var totwLeg = element.id;
     var splitNumero = totwLeg.split(/([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)/);
     var getNumero = splitNumero[2];
     var getDay = splitNumero[3];
     var EmpId = document.getElementById('num1').value;
     var WeekEnding = document.getElementById('theDate').value;
     var DateOccur = document.getElementById('row1' + getDay).innerHTML;
     var JobNum = getNumero - 2;
     var Customer = getNumero - 2;
     var HourValue = document.getElementById('num' + getNumero + getDay).value;
     var cnt = 0;
     Empdata = 'EmpData' + cnt + '';
     temp = {
         EmpId, WeekEnding, DateOccur, JobNum, Customer, HourValue
     };
     SqlArr.push({
         Empdata: temp
     });


 }
```

Results

```
temp=EmpId="2", WeekEnding="09-19-2015",DateOccur="09-14-2015",JobNum=6,Customer=6,HourValue="2"
```

Desired Results

```
temp={EmpId="2", WeekEnding="09-19-2015",DateOccur="09-14-2015",JobNum=6,Customer=6,HourValue="2"},{EmpId="2", WeekEnding="09-19-2015",DateOccur="09-16-2015",JobNum=6,Customer=6,HourValue="4"},{EmpId="2", WeekEnding="09-19-2015",DateOccur="09-16-2015",JobNum=6,Customer=6,HourValue="5"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is all that's wrong but first take `var SqlArr = [];` out of your `function tott()`. Every time you call the function you create a new empty array. So when you call `SqlArr.push()` your always pushing the first item on the array.

OK it looks like it's working to me. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r1L9oj80/1/

However you might look at your 'DateOccur' variable. it contains your entire input element.

Comment: Yea I understand... This was for testing purposes... let me fix that... in the original script it is a global variable

Answer (score 1):

Your `temp` object is invalid, try it like this...

```
temp = {
  'EmpId': EmpId, 'WeekEnding': WeekEnding, 'DateOccur': DateOccur, 'JobNum': JobNum, 'Customer': Customer, 'HourValue': HourValue
};
```

plus the array `SqlArr` should be defined outside the function as mentioned in another answer...